# How would one precisely adjust axis, ticks, and a grid using JSXGraph library?

Tags: javascript, graphics, jsxgraph

What would be the best approach to creating the graph just like the one below using JSXGraph?  For example, how would I make axis go beyond the grid, etc.?

[image]

Have looked at the official documentation and external guides.  Could not find information on how to adjust the ticks, grid, and axis so that I can generate the included graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, axis configuration is sort of complicated in JSXGraph. First, I would not recommend to use the deprecated *grid*, since it does not have tick labels. For configuration of default axes, JSXGraph has the attribute `defaultAxes`.

The horizontal axis can be accessed by the sub-attribute `x`, the vertical axis by `y`.

Now, we do the following to imitate the above image:

1. Turn off automatic tick positioning by `insertTicks: false`
2. The *x*-axis has labels at every other tick line: `minorTicks: 1`
3. The *y*-axis has labels at every tick line: `minorTicks: 0`
4. Both axes have labels for 2, -2, 4, -4, 6, ...: `ticksDistance: 2`
5. If the automatic tick positioning is turned off, there will appear performance problems if users zoom out. Therefore, it might be advisable to limit the zoom factor: `zoom: {min: 0.5, max: 2}`
6. The labels can be styled by supplying a CSS class: `label: {fontSize: 16, display: 'html', cssClass: 'tickLabels'}`

Here is the complete example:

```
const board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', { 
    boundingbox: [-9, 17, 9, -17], axis:true,
    defaultAxes: {
        x: {
        ticks: {
          insertTicks: false, // Turn off automatic tick placing
          minorTicks: 1,      // One minor tick between two major ticks
          minorHeight: -1,    // Minor ticks are finitely long, too
          ticksDistance: 2,   // Major ticks are positioned at multiples of two
          label: {fontSize: 16, display: 'html', cssClass: 'tickLabels'}
        }
      },
        y: {
        ticks: {
          insertTicks: false, // Turn off automatic tick placing
          minorTicks: 0,      // No minor ticks between major ticks
          ticksDistance: 2,   // Major ticks are positioned at multiples of two
          label: {fontSize: 16, display: 'html', cssClass: 'tickLabels'}
        }
      }
    },
    zoom: {
      min: 0.5,
      max: 2
    }
});
```

```
.tickLabels {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1px
}
```

See it live at https://jsfiddle.net/b684vfaL/2/.

- Ticks attributes are described at https://jsxgraph.org/docs/symbols/Ticks.html
- Zoom is documented at https://jsxgraph.org/docs/symbols/JXG.Board.html#zoom

Comment: Thank you for the JSXGraph solution, Alfred.  The design requirements are strict and it appears that producing the desired graphs means dealing with SVG generation directly.